# How to get text value and show in text

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
eText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int wordvalue = 0;
            int numvalue =  0;
            for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
                wordvalue += this.calcCharValue(s.charAt(i));
                numvalue   = this.calcCharValue(s.charAt(i));
                String userEntered = nText.getText().toString();

                userEntered = userEntered + numvalue;

            tv.setText(String.valueOf(wordvalue));
            nText.setText(String.valueOf(userEntered));
        }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        protected int calcCharValue(char a) {
            Character ch = new Character(a);
            if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') { // a=1, b=2, c=3, ..., z=26
                Character ca = new Character('A');
                return ch.charValue() - ca.charValue() + 1;
            }
```

I am try to create an app that get the text value from the word.

for example
 a = 1, b = 2,

I am able to add them like  abc = 6, abcd = 10

Now what my problem is I try this value as

abc = 123 and abcde = 12345

but what I get is

abc = 112123 and abcde = 1 12 123 1234  12345

It repeat the every character before and then add next value so how can I handle this repeated problem.

Comment: `wordvalue += this.calcCharValue(s.charAt(i));` is the cause for this. Basically "+=" is.

Comment: Psy your post is may be not completed please explain

Comment: Your working is similar to that of a Calculator, just without adding any signs.  So I hope you're using `Editable` to append the values.